# About enhanced second chance algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, operating-system

Is that the *lowest nonempty class* I highlighted in the description means the class 1. (0,0)?

And, why it put emphasis on "nonempty"?

--

[image: enhansechan1]
[image: enhansechan2]

Comment: An empty class has no pages in it -- that's what empty means -- so we can't necessarily use the first page in the lowest class: if the lowest class is empty, then we have no candidate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It makes sense because (0,0) is neither *used* nor *modified* - it can be easily replaced with the least amount of work (not modified) and with a low chance of being used again (not used).